# Why will my mysqli statement not be executed in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, basic-authentication

I have an error where the code will direct me to the next page (the product page) and not throw an error, but the SQL is not executed and no new user appears in the database (this is a signup script). Due to the fact that no errors have been thrown when I am redirected despite not being signed up (no new entry is added to the database), I have isolated the problem to the code-snippet shown below, although I cannot myself see anything wrong with it:

```
$hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sss", $email, $hashedPassword, $nationality);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

header("Location: ../productsPage.html?error=loginSuccess");
exit();
```

The exact same code worked perfectly yesterday and I was signed up to the site properly, but today it would appear that it is broken despite me not changing anything as far as I can see.

Please help, thank you.

EDIT: The SQL query is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO usersinfo (userEmail, userPassword, userLocation, userDateJoined) VALUES (?, ?, ?, CURDATE())
```

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: Show us your query.

Comment: Try checking for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) after each step to see if it is providing any errors.

Comment: Where is `$statement` defined?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to why the database would only let me have one entry (hence why it worked for the time I tested it yesterday but not when I tried to add a second entry today). It is because the userID column was a primary key but I forgot to set it to auto-increment, so it was trying and failing to add a duplicate value.

Lesson learned, thanks for all your help!